# Making Server Socket to wait for Client Socket in each iteration

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop, timeout

I start Server program and it waits for Client for just 30 seconds.It works fine in the first iteration and does not wait in the remaining iterations.Any suggestions.

Here the

```
minLinkWt() sets the index.
```

It is however remains the same in the program.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Democ{
 int index,port,min=100;
ServerSocket ss=null;
Socket s=null;

void begin(){
int av=0;boolean b=false;
    minLinkWt();
    while(!b){
    av=checkStatus(index);
    if(av==1){b=true;}
             }
        if(av==1)
        Connect();
        else
        System.out.println("No Routers Available");
}
 void Connect()
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the Message to send to clients::");
    try{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String msg=br.readLine();
    PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ps.println(msg);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
void callSwitch(int index_formal)
{
switch(index_formal)
{
case 1:
port=2000;
break;
case 2:
port=2001;
break;
case 3:
port=2002;  
break;
case 4:
port=2003;
break;
default:
System.out.println("No Routers in Available");
}
}

 int checkStatus(int index_formal){
            try
            {
             ss=new ServerSocket(port);
            ss.setSoTimeout(30000);     
             s=ss.accept();             
            }catch(InterruptedIOException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot connect through Router1 Waiting for Router2");}
            catch(Exception g){g.printStackTrace();}    
            if(s==null)
            return 0;
            else 
            return 1;
    }
class DemoCopy{
public static void main(String s[])
{
Democ obj=new Democ();
obj.begin();
}
}
```

So At every iteration The Server has to wait for the Client but its not waiting.
I get the output as

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
min is6
AT index2
Cannot connect through Router1 Waiting for Router2
No Routers Available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that "index" in the begin() can be index of a array, so you want to check the status of the Server socket port form 0 to x or something.

Probably you should post more source code, but it looks like you are using single port value in the checkStatus(), which means ServerSocket will be bound same port every time.

It's OK at first iteration because server socket is not bound at any port, but at then end of first iteration you didn't close server socket at all.

So Server socket is still bound at given port, and creating new ServerSocket with same port number will be failed since it's already bound and you can't bind it again unless you close it first.

You should use single ServerSocket, and once serverSocket.accept() return socket, then you can store it to array and check it's status frequently. Or maybe you can differentiate port number every time and let client connect different port every time would also work, but I don't think that's what you want to do.

Comment: I have programmed server to listen to  different port numbers in same program.When the first time it listens on say port number 2000 then again if in my code i try to change the port number then i get Connection reset exception.So I have thought this above code.

Comment: Can You suggest me At what point Should I open and close connection sockets to achieve time for wait in this case.

Comment: Wait... if you programmed server to listen different port every time, how will you let client know which ports are available? Based on you question "Making Server Socket to wait for Client Socket in each iteration", you should just open one server socket with specific port number ONLY ONCE, and call serverSocket.accept() in the while loop, that way server will make connection and return socket object which is connected to client side.

Comment: So, it's like 

// create server socket with specific port number (only once)

while (true) {
    // Socket sock = serverSocke.accept();
    // read data from socket, possible reading should be in newly created thread so server side can keep incoming client socket connection.
}